# Django association between three models

Tags: django, database-design, django-models

I have these three models :

- Person.
- Project.
- Role.

Using Django's models system, how to represent the fact that a person is participating in a particular project with a specific role ?

*general problem : What is the proper way to handle "**ternary associations**" using Django ?*

Answer (score 2):

I would do it using an intermediary model for m2m relationship and add a field there.
Something like this:

```
class Role(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_lenth=32)

class Project(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_lenth=32)

class PersonProject(models.Model):
    person = models.ForeignKey('.Person')
    project = models.ForeignKey(Project)

    role = models.ForeignKey(Role)

class Person(models.Model):
    projects = models.ManyToManyField(Project, through=PersonProject)
```

Comment: isn't there a more proper way ?

Comment: @user2080105 Not sure what you mean. This is a proper way to do it... No hacking, no bad practices, it's the supported and recommended Django way as far as I know. What would you prefer? This is the way to make a ternary association in Django. Corresponds to this diagram: http://www.dcs.warwick.ac.uk/~ananda/umlNotes/img57.gif

Comment: Why Person has a ManyToManyField but not Role and Project ?

Comment: @user2080105 Both `Person` and `Project` have a m2m field, the relationship goes both ways. If you add the field on one model, you don't have to do it for the other. If you want the Person to have multiple roles on a single Project, you can change the `role` ForeignKey to also an m2m field, but otherwise there's no need for that.